# Error: It looks like you called `mount()` without a global document being loaded

Tags: reactjs, enzyme

I'm trying to mount a component for testing with enzyme, and get this error.

Comment: Tell us more about your test framework, configuration, etc... but I bet your are using Mocha or an other NOde.js test runner. Mocha doesn't run your test in a browser environment so there is no DOM. You should use karma or simply use `jsdom` npm module to create a DOM.

Comment: I fixed it. Enzyme doesn't display this information in the docs for mocha. You need to require a setup.js with jsdom.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Mocha doesn't run your test in a browser environment,so there is no DOM. To fix this problem,  simply you have to use jsdom npm module to create a DOM.

From [Enzyme docs](http://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/guides/jsdom.html) :

> Since enzyme's mount API requires a DOM, JSDOM is required in order to
>   use mount if you are not already in a browser environment (ie, a Node
>   environment).
>
> JSDOM is a JavaScript based headless browser that can be used to
>   create a realistic testing environment.
>
> For the best experience with enzyme, it is recommended that you load a
>   document into the global scope before requiring React for the first
>   time. It is very important that the below script gets run before
>   React's code is run.
>
> As a result, a standalone script like the one below is generally a good approach:

```
/* setup.js */

var jsdom = require('jsdom').jsdom;

var exposedProperties = ['window', 'navigator', 'document'];

global.document = jsdom('');
global.window = document.defaultView;
Object.keys(document.defaultView).forEach((property) => {
  if (typeof global[property] === 'undefined') {
    exposedProperties.push(property);
    global[property] = document.defaultView[property];
  }
});

global.navigator = {
  userAgent: 'node.js'
};
```

Read [Enzyme documentation - JSDOM](http://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/guides/jsdom.html) for more informations

Comment: Hm, I have the same issue and when I try this I get `TypeError: jsdom is not a function` ... ?

Comment: I have the same issue. Everywhere the solution for global document is jsdom and I just cant get it to run. The above code didn't work. Jsdom version is "15.2.1".

Answer (score 23):

```
npm install --save-dev --save-exact jsdom jsdom-global
```

Then:

```
import 'jsdom-global/register'; //at the top of file, even before importing React
```

More info [here](https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme/issues/341).

**Alternative**: In case you are using jest with enzyme-

In your `package.json`, specify the test environment for jest as `jsdom` as follows:

```
"jest": {
  "testEnvironment": "jsdom"
}
```

I faced the same issue and it worked well for me.

Comment: for jest and enzyme the
`"testEnvironment": "jsdom"` solution is the simplest

Answer (score 4):

just put the following in top of your test file

```
/**
 * @jest-environment jsdom
*/
```

Comment: How does it answer the question?

Comment: Seems unnecessary @bfontaine. I was getting the error in the OP, I put this at the top of my `Cmp.test.js` file, and it fixed it. I'm using jest and enzyme. Alternatively pass `--env=jsdom` to the jest command.