# Testing React Component with Enzyme and Mocha

Tags: reactjs, mocha.js, redux, enzyme

I have the following component in my react redux project and I'm trying to implement tests but running into problems when trying to test the components

**Users.js**

```
export class Users extends Component {
componentWillMount() {
    const dispatch = this.context.store.dispatch;
    dispatch({ type: UserActions.fetchUsers(dispatch)});
}

render() {
    const {users,isFetching} = this.props;
    return (
        <div>
            <CardHeader
                title={this.props.route.header}
                style={{backgroundColor:'#F6F6F6'}}/>
            <UserListHeader/>
            {isFetching ? <LinearProgress mode="indeterminate" /> : <UserList users={users}/>}
        </div>
    )
}
}

Users.propTypes = {
    users: PropTypes.array,
    actions: PropTypes.object.isRequired
};

Users.contextTypes = {
    store: React.PropTypes.object.isRequired
};

function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return {
         users: state.users.users,
         isFetching:state.users.isFetching
   }
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
    return {
        actions: bindActionCreators(UserActions, dispatch)
    }
}

export default connect(
    mapStateToProps,
    mapDispatchToProps
)(Users);
```

and I'm trying to test it like the example on the Redux website, but I'm running into issues

**UsersSpec.js**

```
import {Users} from '/containers/users/Users'
const middlewares = [ thunk ];
const mockStore = configureMockStore(middlewares);

function usersSetup() {
const props = {
    users: expect.createSpy(),
    isFetching:expect.createSpy()
};

const enzymeWrapper = mount(<Users />,{context:{store:mockStore}});

return {
    props,
    enzymeWrapper
}
}

describe('Users', () => {
    it('should render self and subcomponents', () => {
        const { enzymeWrapper } = usersSetup();
        exp(enzymeWrapper.find(UserListHeader)).to.have.length(1);

    })

})
```

But I get the error 'TypeError: dispatch is not a function' should I be mocking the componentWillMount function or how should I test this component.

Should I just be testing the dumb child components? Any guidance would be great. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`mount` function provides full dom rendering therefore you'll need to set up jsdom in your test setup. You can see more info here:

[Error: It looks like you called `mount()` without a global document being loaded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37104033/error-it-looks-like-you-called-mount-without-a-global-document-being-loaded)

Another thing is that, you should provide `childContextTypes` attribute when you're defining `context` with `mount` like this:

```
mount(<Users />, {
    context: { store: mockStore },
    childContextTypes: { store: PropTypes.object }
  });
```

However if you're writing unit test of a React component you should use `shallow` function provided by enzyme. It just renders the component with one deep level, so that you don't need to create jsdom and provide context parameters when you're creating the wrapper component. `mount` rendering in a test means you're actually writing an integration test.

```
const wrapper = shallow(<Users />);
wrapper.find(UserListMenu).to.have.length(1);
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer, I have the jsdom file setup up the problem is 'dispatch is not a function' which stems from my componentWillMount function. So I get this error on shallow or mount. What's the best way to address this problem

Comment: Oh I see, you should not use dispatch in your Component. Since you're passing `actions` as props to your component, you can easily call `this.props.actions.fetchUsers` in your `componentWillMount` function. If you really want to use dispatch in your Component, I think you should define `childContextTypes` in your `mount` function call in your test file.

Comment: ah okay, starting to make sense,   
    'export function fetchUsers(dispatch) {
        dispatch(fetchUsersRequest());
        return fetchUsersApi()
        .then(function(response){dispatch(fetchUsersSuccess(response.data.results))})
        .catch(function(ex){dispatch(fetchUsersFailure(ex))})
}'

above is my action, how do I get around passing dispatch to it, because if I call 'this.props.actions.fetchUsers();' I get 'dispatch is not a function'

Comment: Also it's an async action so it appears I just can't call `this.props.actions.fetchUsers();`